# Sentences with :- helping verbs(except do and have)+to+verb

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive

> If I **were to do** this, it would be better.
>
> All of these **are to be** considered music for us.

I have never seen helping verbs like 'are' and 'were' being used  with 'to' in this way. What do 'were to do' and 'are to be' in these sentences mean ?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv103.shtml).